# ¿Por qué el Título del LabelFrame no aparece en mi aplicacion con Tkinter en Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

El LabelFrame que quiero diseñar tiene un titulo, de tipo:

[image: Imagen de Ejemplo de un LabelFrame **This is a LabelFrame**]

El Recuadro tiene un titulo 'This is a Label' en la parte superior, y lo que busco en mi codigo es un Frame que tenga un titulo similar que diga **Datos de Usuario**

Por alguna razon que no comprendo, la ventana que se ejecuta omite el nombre del frame donde estan contenidos todos los widgets excepto un Label con el mensaje **Sistema de Ingreso de Datos de Usuario**

[image: Esta seria la ventana final ejecutándose]

El Label Frame deberia encerrar los Labels **Usuario y Contraseña** y ambos Entries. El codigo es el siguiente:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Aplicacion(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.create_label()
        self.create_buttons()
        self.create_entries()

    def create_label(self):
        self.label = Label(self, text='Sistema de Ingreso de Datos de Usuario').grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky= W + E)
        self.p_frame = LabelFrame(self, text='Datos de Usuario', bd=1).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.us_label = Label(self.p_frame, text='Usuario').grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.pass_label = Label(self.p_frame, text='Contraseña').grid(row=3, column=0)

    def create_entries(self):
        self.us_entry = Entry(self.p_frame, width=30).grid(row=2, column=1)
        self.pass_entry = Entry(self.p_frame, width=30).grid(row=3, column=1)

    def create_buttons(self):
        self.apply_button = Button(self, text='Aplicar Cambios', relief=GROOVE).grid(row=4, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky= W + E)

def test():
    Aplicacion().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Como se ve es bastante sencillo pero aún asi no se porque no funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en que no estas guardando en la variable `self.p_frame` el objeto `LabelFrame` sino el resultado de la llamada al metodo `grid()`

Debes separar la inicializacion del `LabelFrame` de la llamada a `grid()`

```
    self.p_frame = LabelFrame(self, text='Datos de Usuario', bd=1)
    self.p_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Hola Dani, funciono perfectamente! Gracias por solucionar el problema :) .